# Access Amazon Redshift cluster in an external vendor's AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are looking to access an external vendor's Redshift data. We are on the same platform (AWS). What is the best approach?

Is it possible to directly connect to their Redshift instance as opposed to copy data from their Redshift database to an S3 bucket in our account?

Answer (score 0):

You can create cross account role to access data in redshift of different account.

To set it up visit [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-to-enable-cross-account-amazon-redshift-copy-and-redshift-spectrum-query-for-aws-kms-encrypted-data-in-amazon-s3/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are in Account-A and you wish to access an Amazon Redshift cluster owned by somebody else in Account-B.

#### Network access

The first challenge will be to obtain network access to their cluster.

If their cluster is set to `Publicly Accessible = Yes` and it is in a public subnet, then they can add your IP address to the cluster's Security Group and you should be able to connect directly to the cluster.

If their cluster is *not* publicly accessible, then you could use **VPC Peering** to connect one of your VPCs in Account-A with the their VPC in Account-B that contains the Redshift cluster. It would then be a matter of accessible the Redshift cluster via something in your VPC, such as:

- An Amazon EC2 instance in your VPC
- SSH into the EC2 instance with port forwarding on port 5439
- Point your SQL client to the redirection (okay, not a great explanation, but can provide more details if desired)

#### Login access

They should create a Redshift login with `CREATE USER` and grant the appropriate access to that user.